# In maven-dependency-plugin how to unpack only if I pass him parameter?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin

Does Anyone knows how I can unpack an artifact by terms?

Meaning giving him like a Boolean parameter that will determine whether or not to unpack that certain artifact.

I tried to use the **skip** flag but it didn't work.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>get-rpm</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                          <groupId>com.XX.XXX</groupId>
                          <artifactId>XXX-ONPREM</artifactId>
                          <version>${BUILD_NUMBER}</version>
                          <type>rpm</type>
                          <classifier>rpm</classifier>
                          <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                          <destFileName>${PACKAGE_NAME}</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                      </artifactItems>
                      <!-- other configurations here -->
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                    <id>get-third-parties</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                          <groupId>com.XX.XXX</groupId>
                          <artifactId>thirdparties-sources</artifactId>
                          <version>${third-parties.version}</version>
                          <type>zip</type>
                          <skip>true</skip>
                          <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/3rd-parties</outputDirectory>
                        </artifactItem>
                      </artifactItems>
                      <!-- other configurations here -->
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
```

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to do it? Unpacking 3rd party libs during compile phase does not look normal to me.  I bet what you are doing can be done in a more proper way (e.g. use of assembly plugin).  Anyway, you should be able to put that execution in a separate profile, and control the activation of profile by an env variable.

Comment: It's not during the compile phase, It's being done after my code is being compiled.

Comment: It is in the compile phase. Look closer to your configuration. (That's what I mean that what you are trying to do can be done in a proper way )

Comment: You are right, But what I meant was that the code compilation is being done in a different module. So here the compile phase is not really for compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out,
You simply have to put the **skip** flag in the right place,
I've put it right after the configuration.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>get-rpm</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                          <groupId>com.XX.XXX</groupId>
                          <artifactId>AGM-ONPREM</artifactId>
                          <version>${BUILD_NUMBER}</version>
                          <type>rpm</type>
                          <classifier>rpm</classifier>
                          <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                          <destFileName>${PACKAGE_NAME}</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                      </artifactItems>
                      <!-- other configurations here -->
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                    <id>get-third-parties</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <skip>${SKIP_3rd}</skip>
                      <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                          <groupId>com.XX.XXX</groupId>
                          <artifactId>thirdparties-sources</artifactId>
                          <version>${third-parties.version}</version>
                          <type>zip</type>
                          <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/3rd-parties</outputDirectory>
                        </artifactItem>
                      </artifactItems>
                      <!-- other configurations here -->
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
```